# D3 - passing JSON data through AJAX call

Tags: d3.js

I'm using Ajax to call data which is in JSON format from the server and when its successful want to pass it to D3.

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
        $.ajax({
        url: "{% url 'charts_data' %}",
        method: 'GET',
        data : {
            airline_category: 1,
            year_category: 5
                },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data) // Correctly logs data to console
        d3.json(data, function(dataSet){
            console.log(dataSet) // Null with error 404
        })   
        },
        error: function(error_data){
        console.log("error")
        console.log(error_data)
 }
    })
});
```

I understand I need to provide URL instead data to d3.json. But I want to use this Ajax called data object to build the chart. Ajax called data is in JSON format, how can I use it with D3?

Here is console.log of data:

console.log(data)

[image]

Comment: You have a different problem after your edit. Your original question, which was how to use the AJAX call instead of `d3.json` to get the JSON, was already answered below. The problem you face now is a different one: you have only **one** object in that JSON, and D3 will create only one element. That's the expected behaviour. Why do you expect having several rectangles if you have only one object in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother with `d3.json()` if you already have the data from the `ajax` call. Just do everything in `success` that you would otherwise have done in the body of `d3.json`.

Comment: Thanks, so yes I started doing normal d3 stuff like d3.select("body") and appended "rect" on it and so on. But how will D3 know that this is JSON data and that it has to take keys and values separately and use these for x and y axis?

Comment: @Hannah if the url in the ajax call is a JSON file, d3 will interpret it as a JSON object. What are you seeing in the `console.log` before `d3.json` ?

Comment: Yes its showing JSON before d3.json, let me give it a try.

Comment: I tried and D3 is considering the whole JSON array as one item and appended only one "rect" to the page. I think D3 isnt able to differentiate between keys and values of JSON data. I've added the pic of data with the question for u to look.

Comment: It looks like the `ajax` call is only returning one item from the table. `d3` can interpret that, but it doesn't have enough data to make more than one `rect`. `d3` will make an element for each element in the array, but there's only one element in the returned data array. I'd recommend checking your code for the get operation on the server first.