# D3 - Using JSON data to create multiple bars

Tags: d3.js

I'm learning D3 and have JSON data. I want to build multiple bars from this JSON data to draw graph like this already built in excel. I can draw one line of Pax_Rev on SVG but **I'm not sure how to add other lines from the data.** When I do console.log(dataset.length), it shows me 0 which means only one item in dataset which is expected.

[image]

```
<script>
    var dataset = [{"Pax_Rev": 1000, "Crg_Rev": 500, 
                    "Fixed_Costs": 800, "Variable_Costs": 200}];

    var width = 500;
    var height = 1000;
    var barPadding = 1;

    var svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .append("g")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height)
                .attr("class", "svg")

               svg3.selectAll("rect")
                    .data(dataset)
                    .enter()
                    .append("rect")
                    .attr("x", 0)
                    .attr("y", function(d){
                    return height - d.Pax_Rev // How to add other items like Crg_Rev etc?
                    })
                    .attr("width", 20)
                    .attr("height", function(d){
                    return d.Pax_Rev
                    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have been able to find a work around to change .data(dataset) to following:

.data(Object.values(dataset[0]))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I explained in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45537371/d3-passing-json-data-through-ajax-call), this is the expected behaviour. Since you have just one object in your data array, D3 "enter" selection will create just one element.

If you look at the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_data), you'll see that `selection.data()`:

> Joins the specified **array** of data with the selected elements[...] The specified data is an **array** of arbitrary values (e.g., numbers or objects). (emphases mine)

Therefore, we have to convert that huge object in several objects. This is one of several possible approaches:

```js
var dataset = [{
  "Pax_Rev": 1000,
  "Crg_Rev": 500,
  "Fixed_Costs": 800,
  "Variable_Costs": 200
}];

var data = [];

for (var key in dataset[0]) {
  data.push({
    category: key,
    value: dataset[0][key]
  })
}

console.log(data)
```

Now, we have a `data` array, with several objects, one for each bar, and we can create our bar chart.

Here is a demo:

```js
var dataset = [{
  "Pax_Rev": 1000,
  "Crg_Rev": 500,
  "Fixed_Costs": 800,
  "Variable_Costs": 200
}];

var data = [];

for (var key in dataset[0]) {
  data.push({
    category: key,
    value: dataset[0][key]
  })
}

var svg = d3.select("svg");
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.value
  })])
  .range([120, 10]);
var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.category
  }))
  .range([40, 280])
  .padding(0.2);

var rects = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("fill", "steelblue")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return xScale(d.category)
  })
  .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return yScale(d.value)
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return 120 - yScale(d.value)
  });

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(40,0)").call(yAxis);
svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,120)").call(xAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks Gerardo, I have kind of figured out now.